# Apache2 error log says someone is messing with my server > should I take some action?

Tags: logging, ubuntu, apache-2.2, debian

An example of my `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Sun Apr 10 23:33:12 2011] [error] [client 173.242.122.8] Invalid URI in request GET /bin/scripts/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe /c+dir?/c+dir%20c:\\ HTTP/1.0
[Sun Apr 10 23:33:13 2011] [error] [client 173.242.122.8] Invalid URI in request GET /bin/scripts/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir HTTP/1.0
[Sun Apr 10 23:33:13 2011] [error] [client 173.242.122.8] Invalid URI in request GET /bin/scripts/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir%20c:\\ HTTP/1.0
[Sun Apr 10 23:33:13 2011] [error] [client 173.242.122.8] File does not exist: /var/www/bin
[Sun Apr 10 23:52:20 2011] [error] [client 173.242.122.8] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/allmanage
[Sun Apr 10 23:52:30 2011] [error] [client 173.242.122.8] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/allmanageup.pl
[Sun Apr 10 23:53:02 2011] [error] [client 173.242.122.8] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/AnyBoard.cgi
[Sun Apr 10 23:53:02 2011] [error] [client 173.242.122.8] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/anyboard.cgi
[Sun Apr 10 23:53:03 2011] [error] [client 173.242.122.8] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/AnyForm
[Sun Apr 10 23:53:03 2011] [error] [client 173.242.122.8] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/AnyForm.cgi
[Sun Apr 10 23:53:05 2011] [error] [client 173.242.122.8] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/AnyForm2
```

The list goes on and on, it's **huge**.

Should I take some action against this? Should I be worried? Should I ban the IP?

Answer (score 1):

This is a program scanning for vulnerabilities.

If your site isn't using a vulnerable framework/blog/CMS, then you probably don't have to be overly worried about it; if they didn't find anything, it's just a waste of resources.  If any of the URLs it's tried match URLs on your site, though, then the scanner has done its job -- and the person that was at that IP *at the time the scan was taking place* now has information on how they can break in.  Check your access log for non-4xx responses to that IP during the time of the scan.

Fun part is, the IP may have changed in the past 3 days...so banning the IP at this point probably won't do much good.  About the only surefire ways to keep them out are to update and/or disable the vulnerable apps, and/or take the server down.